# QT - sliding widget

Tags: qt

I'm new in QT interfaces. I would like to create sliding widget in my desktop application (no QML). Idea is to create sliding menu like facebook component on some web pages. 
For example:

1. I have main window and I want to have small part of widget on the right window edge
2. When mouse move on this widget (or click on it) then this widget slide to show all its content.

I know how to create animation and handle mouse events. There is a lot of examples about it. The problem is that this menu widget should not interact with other layouts and widgets. I mean, main window has root horizontal layout and I don't know how to exclude this widget from it and place widget in front of all widgets on main window. Are exists some layers in QT?

Comment: I don't have `Qt` on this machine to test, but I remember being able to do overlapping widgets in the past by using `QFrame`s to hold groups of widgets. The widgets in one frame can expand/move/overlap the ones in the other frame without triggering a layout adjustment. You can probably set up a simple test in `QtDesigner` - just add a couple of frames (play with size/position, and whether one is a child of the other or not), and have a bottom and top widget, and try to resize them.

Comment: Exactly my point is to get similar efect like facebook component on this site (polish) http://www.joemonster.org . On the right edge you have facebook menu and it slide when mouse in on it. Can I get it by QFrame?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish similar functionality by overlaying a custom [QDockWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html). This widget could then float above the other widgets in a fixed position relative to your mainwindow. Connect the main window's resize/move events to slots on your QDockWidget that keeps their positions in sync.

Comment: Exactly my point is to get similar efect like facebook component on this site (polish) http://www.joemonster.org . On the right edge you have facebook menu and it slide when mouse in on it. Can I get it by QDockWidget?

Comment: Play with it on Qt Designer. Simply drop a QDockWidget on the right dock area of your MainWindow and see if it gives you the functionality you're looking for. If so, you'll have to customize its appearance a fair amount (transparent background, no outlines, proper background, etc) to get where you'd like to go.

Comment: Did the same thing with a window.  Works well (this is the info of this comment).  Now,I'll drr if I may move to the QDockWidget as it is much cleaner in point of view of locality (i.e. not another window, but a widget inside the same window)